# Does Windows Embedded Compact 7 support EGL?

Tags: windows-ce, egl

Is [Enterprise Generation Language (EGL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGL_%28programming_language%29) supported in Windows Embedded Compact 7.0?

Comment: Why not searching on google? I'm sure you can find it in the documentation or elsewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is yes.

Details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300132.aspx